# Excess elements in scalar initializer in array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'll admit it's been awhile since I've used C++ but from everything I've looked at, this should work.

```
string clauses[7] = { "-1 2 3 -4 5 6 -7 8", "1 2 3 4", "-5 6 7 8", "-7 8", "5 -6", 
    "3 6", "3 5" };
```

And yet, I get:

> error: excess elements in scalar initializer

Comment: I think this should be just a warning. What flags and compiler do you use?

Comment: [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4646e4bce89641f)

Comment: worked for me too.. no compilation error.
`#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string clauses[7] = { "-1 2 3 -4 5 6 -7 8", "1 2 3 4", "-5 6 7 8", "-7 8", "5 -6", "3 6", "3 5" };
    return 0;
}`

Comment: I'm using the gcc that came with Xcode. Doesn't surprise me that Xcode doesn't like it but I'm wondering why

Comment: works even for vs2008